# C# functions and classes help

Tags: c#, class, list, function, reference

say i have

```
class temp {
  private List<temp3> aList = new List<temp3>();
  public List<temp3> getAList()
  {
     return this.aList;
  }
  public temp() {
  }
}

class temp3 {
  public temp3() {}
}
```

now i have an other class

```
class temp2 {
  private temp t = new temp();

  t.aList.Add(new temp3()); 
}
```

will

```
t.getAList.Add(new temp3());
```

really add temp3 to the aList in temp class?

Comment: please rephrase your questions? whad do you mean by "really add to the aList in temp class"? please explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "a" here ... Please change the name of the "a" class to clarify it ..

Comment: I rephrased a with temp3

Comment: `temp.aList` is private and so `t.aList.Add` will not work!? Why do you think `temp3` will **not** be added into the list? Yes of course it will, but in your case, like I said, `aList` is a private member and is not accessible.

Comment: You have to place the statement in a method too .. You are not allowed to place it directly in a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The line should be:

```
 t.getAList().Add(new temp3());
```

**EDIT** after reading the comments: put that line in a method.

Comment: oops true that was a typo so will it add temp3 to aList in temp class?

Comment: then, yes. Why wouldn't it? did you test it?

Answer (score 2):

`temp.aList` is private, so no that wouldn't work. What you would want to do is add a property to the `temp` class:

```
public List<temp3> AList  
{  
    get {return aList;}  
    set {aList = value;}  
}
```

And then use it as `t.AList.Add(new temp3())`

And as  Akram Shahda point out in the comments, you have to create a method in the class
for it. You can't use statements like that directly in the class.

Answer (score 0):

`aList` is private you cant reach it this way `t.aList.Add(new temp3());` .
you should be using the get method `getAList()`like this `t.getAList.Add(new temp3());`

below code does what you want to do

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

```
namespace Project4
{
  class temp {
  private List<temp3> aList = new List<temp3>();
  public List<temp3> getAList
  {
     get{return aList;}
      set{aList = value;}
  }
  public temp() {
  }
}

class temp3 {
  public temp3() {}
}

class temp2 {
    public static void Method()
    { 
        temp t = new temp();
        t.getAList.Add(new temp3());
    }

}
}
```